# Using Switch and Try Statement to Validate user Input

Tags: java

I've been working on this for a little while and it won't compile. It gives me an error saying

> variable choice might not have been
>   initialized
>                 switch(choice)
>                        ^

but I have that variable set in the program. So I don't know what the problem is? Is it really something else that's keeping this from compiling?

```
 import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class MyType
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String strChoice = "", strTryString, strTryInt, strTryDouble;
            Integer choice, tryInt;
            double tryDouble;
            boolean done = false;

            while(!done)
        {
                try
                {
                    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's my type\n\n\n1) String\n2) integer\n3) double\n4) Quit the program");
                    choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);

                    //test for valid codes 1, 2, 3, or 4
                    if (choice<1 || choice>4) throw new NumberFormatException();
                    else done = true;
                }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a 1, 2, 3, or 4", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    switch(choice)
                {
                        case 1:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct, any input can be saved as a String");
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
                            tryInt = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
                            tryDouble = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            done = true;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit.");
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                        default:  throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI it's `Java`, not `JAVA` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the showInputDialog throws, then 'choice' is not set.

```
try
            {
                String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's my type\n\n\n1) String\n2) integer\n3) double\n4) Quit the program");
                choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);

                //test for valid codes 1, 2, 3, or 4
                if (choice<1 || choice>4) throw new NumberFormatException();
                else done = true;
            }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
```

Comment: okay, i figured it out. I just need to set the integer 'choice' to zero. Thanks

Comment: @Josh: You shouldn't be relying on your code to throw an exception to get to your normal code path.  Though it will always throw the NFE since you are only ever parsing the empty String, not what the user actually inputted (you ignore the `answer` variable).

Answer (score 0):

you should iniatialize the choice variable before try block, as you are referencing it in catch which in some case if the exception is thrown before initialization of choice happining then the varaible choice will be uninitialized.